# longlistselector header/footer click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm very new in WindowsPhone development and at this moment I'm facing a problem that I couldn't find a way to fix. I'm using a LongListSelector to show some information on the device screen and also a Header and a Footer with some static information. Everything looks right, but I can't handle the Click/Tap on the Header and on the Footer (the other items are working properly).

Someone know how to do it? Is there any event that tells my .cs that someone clicked on the footer or on the header view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implement ListFooter and ListHeader in your xaml.

Example :

```
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="myLongListSelector"
                         Background="Transparent"
                         IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                         HideEmptyGroups="True">
           <phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
                  <Grid Height="70" Tap="Grid_Tap">                             
                       <TextBlock Text="Texxt" Foreground="White"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       FontWeight="Bold" 
                                       FontSize="20"/>
                   </Grid>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Now in your cs file, you have :

```
private void Grid_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: It's already done, but how could I know if the "Tap" was on a ListFooter or on a normal item of the list?

Comment: grid_tap event will be triggered only for the footer because your grid is in the footer. For items of longlistSelector, simply set the SelectionChanged event in xaml : <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="myLongListSelector" SelectionChanged="myLongListSelector_SelectionChanged"